# Hide content on menu link secondary click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is some code and a question: how to enable toggle effect after clicking again on menu link button with saving existing functionality? So I need to hide content on second click (secondary click on link one hides content 1, etc.) All other staff is working perfect, but I have something broken in my jQuery. Also, maybe I have too many non-useful lines of code here. Please correct me if you can.

```js
// Dropdown menu functionality

var anchor = $('.main_nav li a');
var menu = $('.menu');

anchor.click(function () {
  if ($(this.getAttribute('href')).hasClass('is-visible')) {
    this.parent.siblings().removeClass('is-visible');
    menu.not(this).removeClass('is-visible').addClass('is-hidden');
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    anchor.not(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this.getAttribute('href')).removeClass('is-hidden').addClass('is-visible');
  }
  return false;
});


$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
  // if the target of the click isn't the menu nor a decendant of the menu
  if (!menu.is(e.target) && menu.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    anchor.removeClass('active');
    menu.removeClass('is-visible').addClass('is-hidden');
  }
});

// hide menu when clicking on links
$('.menu a').click(function () {
    anchor.removeClass('active');
    menu.removeClass('is-visible').addClass('is-hidden');
});
```

```css
.is-hidden {
  display: none;
}

.is-visible {
  display: block;
}

.active {
  background: green;
}

.main_nav {
  padding: 0;
}
.main_nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  background: grey;
  text-align: center;
}
.main_nav li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 30px 0 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu {
  background: grey;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Main navigation -->
<ul class="main_nav">
  <li><a href="#link_1">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#link_2">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#link_3">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#link_4">Link 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#link_5">Link 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#link_6">Link 6</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Div's -->
<div class="menu is-hidden" id="link_1">
  <a href="#">Content 1</a>
</div>
<div class="menu is-hidden" id="link_2">
  <a href="#">Content 2</a>
</div>
<div class="menu is-hidden" id="link_3">
  <a href="#">Content 3</a>
</div>
<div class="menu is-hidden" id="link_4">
  <a href="#">Content 4</a>
</div>
<div class="menu is-hidden" id="link_5">
  <a href="#">Content 5</a>
</div>
<div class="menu is-hidden" id="link_6">
  <a href="#">Content 6</a>
</div>
```

[Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdvbVX) is a pen containing the code for this example.

Comment: Much appreciate for editing, Drew!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution finds me. Only JS below:

```
// Dropdown menu functionality

var anchor = $('.main_nav li a');
var menu = $('.menu');

anchor.click(function () {
  if ($(this.getAttribute('href')).hasClass('is-visible')) {
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('is-visible');
    menu.not(this).removeClass('is-visible').addClass('is-hidden');
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    menu.removeClass('is-visible').addClass('is-hidden');
    anchor.not(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this.getAttribute('href')).removeClass('is-hidden').addClass('is-visible');
  }
  return false;
});

// close menu when clicking on links or button inside of it
$('.menu a, .menu button').click(function () {
    anchor.removeClass('active');
    menu.removeClass('is-visible').addClass('is-hidden');
});

// close menu when clicking inside of it
$('body').click(function(e) { 
  var el = e.target || e.srcElement;
  // if the target of the click isn't the other menu nor navigation link
  if (!$(el).closest('.menu').length && !$(el).closest('.main_nav li a').length) { 
    anchor.removeClass('active'); 
    menu.removeClass('is-visible').addClass('is-hidden'); 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your onClick function on anchors are not working exactly as you had in mind. Here's what I'm going to do:

1. First, let's get rid of other functions, mouseup and menu click. You can elaborate on those matters later.
2. For the problem at hand, your anchor click function, just toggle the divs. You can select which div to show/hide by using the *href*s.

Just remove the dash from the *href* and sent it to jQuery selector. Then you can toggle it. I seperated the code into multiple lines for the sake of understanding.

Hope this helps.

```
anchor.click(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr("href").replace('#', '');
    var div = $('#' + href);
    $('div.menu').not(div).hide();
    $(div).toggle();
});
```

Here's a [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvdyLX)

Comment: Thanks, and how to close already opened div after clicking on next link, for example?

Comment: for that, you'll just hide other divs before toggling the appropriate one with this: $('div.menu').not(div).hide();. I updated the pen.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I want.

Comment: if it works for you, then please accept the answer and let's move on to other endeavours

Comment: It's not a full answer to my problem,  I add more suitable one below. It's fully worked.

Comment: alrighty then. you can always accept your own answer though

Answer (score 1):

What you really want is, just hide other divs except the selected one, when you click on the respective link and again hide it with second click.
Well It doesn't need  that kind of messy javascript code

```js
$(function(){
       $('.clicker').click(function(e){    
                $('.menu').hide();
                $('#link_'+$(this).attr('target')).toggle();
         });
});
```

```css
.menu{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Main navigation -->
<ul class="main_nav">
  <li><a href="#" target="1" class="clicker">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" target="2" class="clicker">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" target="3" class="clicker">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" target="4" class="clicker">Link 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" target="5" class="clicker">Link 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" target="6" class="clicker">Link 6</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Div's -->
<div class="menu" id="link_1">
  <a href="#">Content 1</a>
</div>
<div class="menu" id="link_2">
  <a href="#">Content 2</a>
</div>
<div class="menu" id="link_3">
  <a href="#">Content 3</a>
</div>
<div class="menu" id="link_4">
  <a href="#">Content 4</a>
</div>
<div class="menu" id="link_5">
  <a href="#">Content 5</a>
</div>
<div class="menu" id="link_6">
  <a href="#">Content 6</a>
</div>
```

.
I think this must be a complete solution for your problem.

Comment: Notice that if you will click on other links, previous links will itself get hidden.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working properly right, I need to hide each of the div with its link and safe my existing functionality.